# Scrollable Textview in Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I am working on constraint layout I have three views. First is on top and 2nd have relative position to view1 and then last is below the view 2. Now in 2nd view I have textview which should be scrollable. Problem is scrollview height covering full screen but I want it to have fix height and do not move view 3 out of the screen. I do not want to hard code the height of scrollview so did know what should be the other way to solve it. In short 2nd view should remain between the view 1 and view 3 regardless of text length.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/aandn_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/aandn_icon" />


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrolltext"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/start_tv4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/sound"
                android:layout_gravity="top|left"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sound"
                android:text="Definition: A happening or sudden event that is not wanted or expected.Example: The cars collided unexpectedly on the road causing an accident.||
Definition: A happening or sudden event that is not wanted or expected.Example: The cars collided unexpectedly on the road causing an accident.||
Definition: A happening or sudden event that is not wanted or expected.Example: The cars collided unexpectedly on the road causing an accident.||
Definition: A happening or sudden event that is not wanted or expected.Example: The cars collided unexpectedly on the road causing an accident.||
Definition: A happening or sudden event that is not wanted or expected.Example: The cars collided unexpectedly on the road causing an accident.||
Definition: A happening or sudden event that is not wanted or expected.Example: The cars collided unexpectedly on the road causing an accident.||
Definition: A happening or sudden event that is not wanted or expected.Example: The cars collided unexpectedly on the road causing an accident.||
Definition: A happening or sudden event that is not wanted or expected.Example: The cars collided unexpectedly on the road causing an accident.||
Definition: A happening or sudden event that is not wanted or expected.Example: The cars collided unexpectedly on the road causing an accident.||
Definition: A happening or sudden event that is not wanted or expected.Example: The cars collided unexpectedly on the road causing an accident.||
Definition: A happening or sudden event that is not wanted or expected.Example: The cars collided unexpectedly on the road causing an accident.||
Definition: A happening or sudden event that is not wanted or expected.Example: The cars collided unexpectedly on the road causing an accident.||
Definition: A happening or sudden event that is not wanted or expected.Example: The cars collided unexpectedly on the road causing an accident.||
Definition: A happening or sudden event that is not wanted or expected.Example: The cars collided unexpectedly on the road causing an accident.||
Definition: A happening or sudden event that is not wanted or expected.Example: The cars collided unexpectedly on the road causing an accident.||
Definition: A happening or sudden event that is not wanted or expected.Example: The cars collided unexpectedly on the road causing an accident.||
Definition: A happening or sudden event that is not wanted or expected.Example: The cars collided unexpectedly on the road causing an accident.||
Definition: A happening or sudden event that is not wanted or expected.Example: The cars collided unexpectedly on the road causing an accident.||
Definition: A happening or sudden event that is not wanted or expected.Example: The cars collided unexpectedly on the road causing an accident.||
"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp" />


        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrolltext"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/aandn_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. "
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView4" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**this is the output**

[image]

Comment: try  android:lines="5" in second textview. it will scroll after some lines.

Answer (score 3):

You want to stick `textView4` to the bottom of the screen and let the `ScrollView` fill in above that but below the top `TextView`. If my understanding is correct, here is an approach:

To stick `textView4` to the bottom of the screen:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    ...
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
```

This is the image view, but the text view is tied to it.

To fill the center portion with the `ScrollView`:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrolltext"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/imageView4"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">
```

The height of the scroll view is set to `MATCH_CONSTRAINTS` (0dp) with the top and bottom constrained the scroll view's associated image view and the bottom image view. This will center the scroll view between those two constraints, so the vertical bias is needed to shift the scroll view to the top of the range.

Answer (score -1):

**ConstraintLayout allows you to create large and complex layouts with a flat view hierarchy (no nested view groups).** [@](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html)

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"                                             
android:layout_height="match_parent"                                            
android:layout_margin="20dp">

<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/imageView"
 android:layout_width="48dp"
 android:layout_height="48dp"
 app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
 app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

<TextView
 android:id="@+id/textView"
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
 android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
 android:minHeight="48dp"
 android:text="Lorem ipsum"
 app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
 app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"/>

<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/imageView2"
 android:layout_width="48dp"
 android:layout_height="48dp"
 android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
 app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
 app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>


<ScrollView
 android:id="@+id/scrolltext"
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_height="0dp"
 app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView4"
 app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
 app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
 app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
 app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">
    <TextView
     android:id="@+id/start_tv4"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_gravity="top|start"
     android:text="@string/huge_text"
     android:textColor="#000000"
     android:textSize="20sp"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView4"
     app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"/>

</ScrollView>

<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/imageView4"
 android:layout_width="48dp"
 android:layout_height="48dp"
 android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
 app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrolltext"
 app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

<TextView
 android:id="@+id/textView4"
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_height="0dp"
 android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
 android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
 android:minHeight="48dp"
 android:text="@string/lorem"
 app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
 app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
 app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
 />
```

Rest can be figured out.